# "the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented" for a vector of structs with a generic type

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to set a value in a struct with an `Any` type in a generic, i'm going to use it later for writing to redis.

```
struct Property<T> {
  value: T,
}
struct Process {
  properties: Option<[Property<Any>]>,
}
```

This returns an error:

```
the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `[Property<core::any::Any + 'static>]`
```

**Edit**

After reading all the links from the comment, I would like to explain that I would love to have a property that can accept any primitive type as a value:

```
use std::any::*;

struct Property<T> {
    value: T,
}

struct Process {
    properties: Option<Property<Any>>,
}

fn main() {
    let p = Process {
            properties: Some(
                Property::<String>{
                    value: ""
                }
            )
        };

    let p2 = Process {
            properties: Some(
                Property::<u32>{
                    value: 150
                }
            )
        };
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why this isn't a duplicate of any of the similar ones. You **did** search for the error message, I assume. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28175528/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/32446485/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/32618872/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/26922353/155423 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/26062892/155423?

Comment: Especially [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28175528/155423) which deals explicitly with `[T]`...

Comment: And to be clear, this *may not be a duplicate*, but it is expected that you show some amount of effort and show what research you've done. Often that means pointing at existing SO questions that are close but leave something unexplained.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster, sorry for the perception of lack of effort, i researched some of the answers, i believe i'm too new to rust to know what to look for, i'll try to fix based on your answers and i hope not to ask any additional dumb "duplicated" questions.

Comment: Don't worry too much! In the end it should help you out as well. If you were confused by a previous question or answer, it won't help of we simply say the same thing again. Pointing out your research helps us give you information that is highly relevant to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vector instead:

```
struct Process {
  properties: Option<Vec<Property<Any>>>,
}
```

The error says, that `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented, so the size is not known at compile time.

See [here](http://rustbyexample.com/primitives/array.html) for little more information about the distinction between arrays and vectors.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't a duplicate of one of the ones I've mentioned in the comments on the question?

Comment: Because I didn't see the comments until you wrote this comment :)